# io.elementary.files fails to start and returns "Failed to register: Timeout was reached"

Tags: pantheon-files

For some reason the Files app started failing (does not start as non root user)

It returns "Failed to register: Timeout was reached"

I am not exactly sure what triggered this. The only thing I can think of is that I have been trying to setup a vpn connection using f5fpc and openconnect-vpn.openconnect but I don't know whether it is related.

Any tips how to fix or debug this?

Many thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It's ok again. My guess is because of a very slow usb drive.

Peter